# Overriding views from main app in engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am presently working with themes. I need to write a function in the main application_controller to add a path in the engine_controller so that it looks for views in the main app themes before looking for the same views in the Engine.

I do not wish to make any edits to the engine i have made and the view path must be prepended to the engine view load path from the Main application `application_controller`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: I have tried to create the same structure as in the engine and tried to render my partials from the engine itself. which are both undesirable. I am a beginer and can not exactly find out how to send a  prepend_view_path from the main application controller to the sengine application controller. I have written my own function set_views_path where in the path to be followed for loading the views is followed. But i do not want to make any amends or changes to this function. The whole thing must be handled by the parent app. After a lot of googling i have still not been able to get it.